# Can I make -Wincomplete-patterns more strict?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, warnings, ghc

With GHC, I can enable `-Wincomplete-patterns` to catch likely erroneous situations like these two.

```
problem1 :: Either Int String -> Int
problem1 (Left x) = x

problem2 :: Either Int String -> Int
problem2 x = case x of
               Left x' -> x'
```

Clearly, I've forgotten to handle the `Right` case in both of these functions, and GHC will tell me that. However, the compiler seems to let me off without even a warning in these two cases.

```
problem3 :: Either Int String -> Int
problem3 x = let Left x' = x in x'

problem4 :: Either Int String -> Int
problem4 = \(Left x) -> x
```

I still forgot to handle a case, but GHC doesn't seem bothered. Is there a compiler flag I can set to catch situations like this where I use `let` or lambda pattern matching but didn't handle all of the cases? Ideally, I want to be warned if I do something like this so I can refactor it into a `case` statement or the like.

Of course, for the sake of completeness and posterity, answers relevant to other compilers are highly appreciated as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `-Wincomplete-uni-patterns` is what you need. As someone who uses `-Wall` basically all the time, I find the fact that those cases aren't covered by `-Wall` or `-Wincomplete-patterns` surprising and bad.

**EDIT**: It appears a GHC proposal to add this to `-Wall` was accepted. I'm not sure the status (I checked on 8.4): https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/pull/71

Comment: I do use ugly stuff like `\(Left x)-> x)` in e.g. test code or throwaway scripts, but I think I'd rather disable the warning for specific files. Also how does this work on `LambdaCase`? I really have no idea (it turns out `-Wincomplete-patterns` is sufficient there)

Comment: As a fellow `-Wall` user, I sympathize with your sadness that this check is not included. But it seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!